# Custom keywords for search engines in Firefox gone?

Tags: firefox

How do I manage my search engines keywords in the new Firefox?

I used to be able to type "y something" to look for "something" on youtube. I would give a keyword to each of my search engines.

For example I would just have to type "fren giraffe" to go on the wordreference page of giraffe from french to english.

I updated firefox and now the "manage search engine" part is gone. Any idea how to make it back?

Comment: I see my keywords displaying in the Search tab of the Options dialog (also accessible via Change Search Settings in the Search bar), but there no longer seems to be a way to edit those.  I wonder what file these are stored in, I don't see any of the search engines/keywords appearing in my bookmarks.

Answer (score 4):

I found this tutorial how to set it up. I tried it on my Mac and it worked. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar

You can edit them in your bookmark menu. Choose the bookmark(search engine keyword) you want to edit and use the down arrow at the bottom. Some more options will appear where you can edit the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [roymeo](https://superuser.com/questions/850883/custom-keywords-for-search-engines-in-firefox-gone#comment1205097_850883) was on the right track.

1. Open the drop-down menu on the Search box and choose "Change Search Settings" from it.
2. Observe that the list of search engines on that page of settings has a "keyword" column
3. Double click within that column on the row for a given search engine to begin editing the keyword for that engine.

I only managed to figure this out after kludging through it with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30408067/294313), so that I actually had something in said column to try clicking on, but I went on to try adding a new keyword by double clicking an empty keyword entry and that worked too.